# I am using Google Maps service (Places, directions). After using for a while I am receiving response :

Tags: android

I am using Google Maps service for Places and directions After using for a while I am receiving response from server.

{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}

please solve this problem

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to upgrade to a paid plan to raise your query limit. See https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/